# C fscanf - formatting input

Tags: c, string, input, char, scanf

How can I format fscanf to format the input
`{'name surname', 'username', points}` to strings which do not contain apostrophes

```
fscanf(fp,"{%s %s %d}",name,username,username1);
```

Comment: Scan sets — `%[…]`

Comment: "strings which do not contain apostrophes" is unusual as names sometimes contains  apostrophes.  [Why do some people have an apostrophe/hyphen in their name?](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-some-people-have-an-apostrophe-hyphen-in-their-name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
fscanf(fp,"{'%[a-zA-Z ]', '%[a-zA-Z ]', %d}",name,username,username1);
```

Comment: You could use `%[^']` more succinctly, and allow hyphenated names.  Mr O'Rourke still suffers, of course, but that's a definitional problem for the questioner.  It's also curious that `username1` is a pointer to an integer.  Often, that would be `&username1` — but without the variable definitions, it's hard to know what's correct.  It would be good to put upper bounds on the number of characters read into the strings to avoid buffer overflow (`%49[^']` for `char name[50];`).  And the return value should be tested to ensure 3 values were read.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Regarding your comment: "_You could use %[^'] more succinctly"_.  Keeping it simple, I have tried `"{'%[^'], '%[^'], %d"`, (matches only 1 parameter, the 1st one), and have also tried `"{'%[^'], '%[a-zA-Z], %d"`. with same result.  Can you explain then how exactly would you use `%[^']` more succinctly?

Comment: @ryyker: You should have looked for the quote before the comma (twice): `"{'%[^']', '%[^']', %d"`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Still fuzzy on extensive and correct usage of this parsing method, but that helps.  Thank you!

Comment: @ryyker: The negated scan set is a trifle dangerous — it includes newlines, for example, so if the data is malformed, things could go badly awry, especially without lengths to protect from buffer overflow.  It would be safer to use `%49[^'\n]` as the scan set, for example (assuming `char name[50];`).  It would probably be better to use `fgets()` to read lines and then `sscanf()` to parse it; that avoids the newline fiasco, and allows a second chance at parsing the line if Mr O'Rourke's name turns up in the data.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation–]_ You could simply be more inclusive: `%49[a-zA-Z -]` to scan for letters, blanks, dashes.  If you could have Mr. P. J. O'Neil in the data, add `.` to the list.  Note that the dash on its own must be first or last.  That then leaves those with accents in their names unreadable (UTF-8 presents extra problems).  The negated scan set also allows digits and other punctuation into the name field — that may or may not be a significant problem.  GIGO — Garbage In, Garbage Out.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Good information, thank you again.  And Yes! I find `fgets()` in combination with `strtok()` to be intuitive and sufficient for almost any predictable, repeatable input, such as multiple field table contents of a file for example.  But because this topic (scansets) comes up often I think it would be worth knowing.